# Sorting list items in a webpart in SharePoint

Tags: list, web-part, sorting

How do you sort list items in a web part in SharePoint in the order that you want?

Answer (score 1):

- From the above ribbon, select modify view   >

[image]

- Beside sort  try to sort as ASC or Disc based on your column that you need to sort with it

[image]

- At list view web part > edit web part > and select this view

[image]

You can also create your custom view from

> List setting > Scroll down to the below of the page > click create view > and sort as you want.

and set it to list web part as mentioned above.

[image]